# How to shutdown Azurite process that was started by Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, process, azure-storage-emulator, azurite

Visual Studio 2022 > Connected Services > Storage Azurite emulator (Local)

On most searches I've read that Azurite is a Node.js process which can only be stopped from cmd.exe via ctrl-c or closing cmd.exe window ( or obviously restarting OS ).

On project startup VS will start Azurite process but without a cmd.exe  window.

Azurite process will live on even after VS is closed.

It's not clear how to stop the Azurite process started by VS.

Also what I find peculiar is this exe :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\azurite.exe
```

If Azurite is Node.js then what is this ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to shutdown Azurite process that was started by Visual Studio 2022: -

As you mentioned already, it is correct that Azurite is a Node.js process which can be stopped with `ctrl-c` cmd.exe in cmd window.

[image]

The `azurite.exe` file works as a wrapper for the `Node.js` process.
Visual Studio uses this to launch Azurite with certain configurations and environment variables required for its integration.

When Visual Studio is managing `Azurite`, it utilizes this wrapper instead of directly executing the `Node.js` executable.

*But there are few other approaches to stop the Azurite process completely which are detailed below.*

1. You can use taskkill command to kill the azurite process by providing `process ID` (PID) or directly `azurite.exe` name along with the command.
   Note: Obtain the process ID from VS Azurite running window. Or execute `tasklist` command to get the process related details.

   ```bash
   tasklist /fi "services eq Azurite"
   taskkill /F /IM azurite.exe or taskkill /pid PID /f
   ```

[image]

2. Use `taskmanager` by searching in the `start` menu in your pc and search for `azurite >> end task` as shown below.

[image]

3. And the last approach would be with the visual studio window itself. Right click on the `storage emulator` under your application and click on `disconnect`. The process will get stopped automatically.

[image]

*References:*
[Blog](https://devcodef1.com/news/1145654/azurite-process-shutdown-in-vs2022#:%7E:text=Once%20you%20have%20located%20the%20Azurite%20process,%20you,/F,%20replacing%20%5BPID%5D%20with%20the%20actual%20process%20ID.),
[taskkill](https://www.windows-commandline.com/taskkill-kill-process/)